# Pull Footer Value As String

Tags: vba, footer

Is there anyway to the pull the value of the footer as a string, and not the formula to make that footer?

Can provide more information if this is a possibility.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code so the community can help you.

Comment: <duh> Which application are you talking about? Word has footers. So do Excel and PowerPoint. All do it differently.Or something else entirely? Use the [edit] link to add all relevant information to your question. We aren't mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim mystring As String
mystring = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
Debug.Print mystring
```

Comment: I am actually using Excel. Any formula for that?

Comment: You used `ms-word` and `word-vba` as your tags. That's probably why it's tailored to Word.

Comment: @IvenBach No that's my fault IvenBach, I added those tags. The only tags before were `vba` and `footer`, which is very ambiguous and I assumed he was talking about `ms-word`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Dim myFooter As String

myFooter = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter
```

of course you may want to use

```
myFooter = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter
myFooter = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter
```

Comment: My apologies to all for not providing enough information. I am attempting to pull a footer in excel that I created through a previous macro (seen below). However when pulling in the footer, I am left with either ""&""Times New Roman,Bold""&10&KFF0000&P" or "ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter". I want the final result of the footer "AB.4" and not the text of the macro that built the footer. Let me know if any more details are needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dim currentName As String
    Dim shName As String
    Dim MySheet As String
        currentName = ActiveSheet.Name
        If InStr(currentName, ".") > 0 Then
        MySheet = (Split(currentName, ".")(0))
        Else: MySheet = (Split(currentName, " ")(0))
        End If
        shName = "&""Times New Roman,Bold""&10&KFF0000" & MySheet + "."
        Dim shNumber As String
        shNumber = "&""Times New Roman,Bold""&10&KFF0000&P"
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .RightFooter = shName & shNumber
        End With
        Application.PrintCommunication = True